# Instantiating a Class in Interactive Python Shell

Tags: python, class, ubuntu, command-line

in a .py file I have the following:

```
class avgbox:
    def __init__(self,t,n,a):
        self.t = t
        self.n = n
        self.a = a
    def add(x):
        self.t += x
        self.n += 1
        self.a = t/n
```

Now when I do the `from file.py import *` in the interactive python shell run from the ubuntu command line, it shows no error. Then when do `a = avgbox(0,0,0)` it says `NameError: name 'avgbox' is not defined`. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Using `from foo import *` is nearly always a bad idea.

Comment: try `from file import avgbox`

Comment: you also need `self` as the first argument in the `add` method!

Comment: I think `from file.py import *` should be throwing an error. Try `from file import *`.

Comment: Most likely, you didn't restart your interactive interpreter and get a cached version of the module that doesn't yet contain the class `avgbox`.  Try `from file import avgbox`, and if this doesn't work, restart your interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

I copy pasted your code into a file named "file.py". Then I did the following:

```
from file import *

avgbox(1, 2, 3)
```

It worked. Maybe your mistake was that you were doing `from file.py import *` when you should just be doing `from file import *` Remember that when Python searches for module names, it automatically appends `.py` to the name of the module if it's looking for a Python file within the current directory. Of course, you can also search within packages using the `from` syntax, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that the file is in the same directory as your python interpreter is. You must also remove the `.py` in the `from file.py import *` as the `.py` signifies a different module in a package, for example `import os.path`. If the file is *not* in the same directory as the python shell, you must make sure that python is able to find it in your `PATH` variable.

It is also notable that you should not usually do a `from file import *` as this will pollute the namespace that you import it into, as it imports it as `function_names` instead of `module.function_names`. You can do `from file import function1,function2,...` and this will only import those functions into the current namespace, and no others.

Also, make sure that in a class you put `self` as the first parameter for each function in the class, as it will raise a syntax error if you don't.